# Create two different rules on .htaccess: redirect some urls to my old site and create 301 redirects for news from my old to new site

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to understand how to redirect some urls that on my new site are not yet active but redirect a few other to new imported page on my new website
Example

I have and joomla website i'd like to redirect
`www.mywebsite.it/it` to `old.mywebsite.it/it`

But have also some spercific 301 redirects for news and some page
`it/notizie/2036-slugnews.html` to `notizie/year/notizia/slugnews`

I'm working on Apache2, with mysql 5.7, php 7.2 and October Cms.
With mod_rewrite enabled and laravel

Read some examples on:
https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/introduction-to-redirects

Imagined i have to try to write a condition that get all urls after `/it/*`but insert an exception to write all except the ones with 301 redirects

Honestly can't figure out how to redirect write the condition.

Have you some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should place your special url redirects before general rule in your .htaccess file:
For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^it/notizie/2036\-slugnews\.html$ http://old.mywebsite.it/notizie/year/notizia/slugnews? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.it$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old.mywebsite.it/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If You new to redirects, I can suggest to use https://www.301-redirect.online/ [301 redirect generator](https://www.301-redirect.online/) for your special page to page rules. This generator is the best one I know at this moment.

Also, change http:// to https:// if your site uses secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

after a series on trials i have found an intermediate solution:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/it(.*)$ https://www.mysite.it$1
RewriteRule ^it/genericpage.html https://www.mywebiste.it/genericapagetoredirect? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^it/notizie/2002-slug.html https://www.mywebiste.it/notizie/2019/notizia/slugtoberedirected? [R=301,L]
```

In this way i redirect my old https://www.mysite.it/it home page to https://www.mysite.it
and some urls with a one to one redirect

But is not my goal.

Reasoning on the subject i found the defnitive solution

My goal is to redirect 
1) a bunch of url with a rewrite url 301
2) All the links which are not included in the list of rewrite url genrically to https://www.mysite.it
3) All bad link joomla website create from www.mysite.it/it/tags/* and www.mysite.it/it/components/* to www.mysite.it

In general the goal frankly is to mantain linked urls with high authority in the google search console.

Aware of this i tried to

```
    RewriteRule ^it/genericpage\.html$ https://www.mywebiste.it/genericapage? [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.it$
    RewriteRule ^it/$ https://www.mysite.it/? [R=301,L]
```

and

```
    RewriteRule ^it/genericpage\.html$ https://www.mywebiste.it/genericapage?[R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.it$
    RewriteRule ^it(/.*) $1 [R=301,L]
```

But without success.

What do you think?